# Ruby Best Practice For Storing Collection of Procs

Tags: ruby

I am writing regressive test for my app and I use the class `Page`. Each page has a `nav_to` method that needs to be set with a proc when the instance is initialized.

I currently have a list of 40 some procs in the global scope and to me this seems sloppy. What would be the best practice for storing these procs? Should I store them in a module? Hash? Class? Please help!

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider storing them in a module- (or class-)constant so that they can be grouped and named clearly.  The data structure you choose (array vs hash) probably depends most on your desired interface (are they associated with some key or simply ordered?) and performance concerns, if relevant:

```
module MyTests # ...or "class"

  NAV_TO_PROCS = [
    Proc.new { ... },
    Proc.new { ... },
  ]

  # ... or ...

  NAV_TO_BY_PAGE_NAME = {
    "page1" => Proc.new { ... },
    "page2" => Proc.new { ... },
  }

end
```

As an aside, when using module constants as such I like to "freeze" them to avoid accidental mutation during use (e.g. `NAV_TO_PROCS = [...].freeze`).